JMeter does not Uploads the PDF file
I am not sure what's wrong, it does not throws any error. PDF file not uploaded.I have tried by giving the parameter name as fileNames[] , but no luck. I have tried by unselecting multipart.form-data and with Body Data also did not work. I am really stuck, much appreciated for the help!  I have attached the Request headers & Request Data from the F12 for the reference, where  will see 3 pdf files when  i did manually a from the application. Through the Jmeter I am trying only 1 PDF.
POST https:xxxxxxxx/corewebservice/api/document/upload/bulk/presigned/validate
POST data:
--XTPbMaSotokYaD6oRvN5X82gbhKnXSe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Size"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

31045
--XTPbMaSotokYaD6oRvN5X82gbhKnXSe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="documentTypeId"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

1
--XTPbMaSotokYaD6oRvN5X82gbhKnXSe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="objectType"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

3
--XTPbMaSotokYaD6oRvN5X82gbhKnXSe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="objectTypeKeyType"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

intake
--XTPbMaSotokYaD6oRvN5X82gbhKnXSe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="tagTextCsv"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


--XTPbMaSotokYaD6oRvN5X82gbhKnXSe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileNames[]"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

BLANK_TestChart.pdf
--XTPbMaSotokYaD6oRvN5X82gbhKnXSe
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pdfDocument"; filename="BLANK_TestChart.pdf"
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--XTPbMaSotokYaD6oRvN5X82gbhKnXSe--

[no cookies]







The section for the actual PDF data has a Content-Type: multipart/form-data. Shouldn't that be application/octet-stream or application/pdf? multipart/form-data surely is wrong here.

@mkl please see I have attached  F12 screenshots

I'm not experienced with jmeter. I merely spotted the error in the POST data above: The request as a whole indeed must have multipart/form-data content type but each form-data element in the data must have its appropriate content type. MAybe someone else can explain how to configure jmeter for that.

Given you're capable of uploading the file using your browser the easiest way of building a proper HTTP Request sampler would be just recording your request from the browser using JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
Just remember to copy the file(s) you will be uploading to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation - this way JMeter will be able to properly intercept the request and generate appropriate HTTP Request Sampler and HTTP Header Manager
More information: A Guide to the JMeter File Upload/Download Feature

You just need to put the file in the same folder as the jmeter script.
In addition to that, you must fill the fields at the "File Upload" tab:
File path: the absolute path of the file
Parameter name: the field name
MIME Type: the file type
